# How can I preserve color in console text for printing?

Tags: printing, colors, console-application, windows-console

I've got a custom windows command-line diff utility that spits out nice white/green/red console text output about what has been changed/added/deleted.

I need to print out the output, but standard commands to either dump the output to file or copying/pasting to another document lose all the coloring information in the text.  (And, the coloring is where all the information is.)

Is there any way to get colored text from a windows command prompt (or power shell window, or and other shell replacement that can run a windows command-line app) into a printable form that retains the text coloring?

Comment: ConEmu can copy the screen as HTML or ANSI sequences. As a console replacement, it works by hiding the original Windows console and hooking the console API to redirect console I/O to its own window.

Comment: It's not a "cmd" or "PowerShell" window. It's all the same console, hosted by conhost.exe. PowerShell can access the text attributes, as demonstrated in this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/01/11/colorized-capture-of-console-screen-in-html-and-rtf). A C/C++ console app would get get the screen buffer size via [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683171) and read the screen, including text attributes, via [`ReadConsoleOutput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684965).